# Pop-up hyperlink to local network in Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-portal, hyperlink

I am working in ArcMap 10.5 and published a feature service to the Portal for ArcGIS. One of the features I have published has a field which contains a hyperlink to a folder on our local network.

Is there a way to click the hyperlink in the pop-up window that will access the folder on our local network?

Comment: I have a similar issue, trying to open a folder not launch a file when the link is clicked, is there anyway to do that?